# Need help recursively pulling in a parent's parent to create a tree R

Tags: r, recursion, tree, lookup

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

| name | manager |
| --- | --- |
| John | Bill |
| Bill | David |
| David | Sarah |
| Sarah |  |

```
name = c("John","Bill","David","Sarah")
manager = c("Bill","David","Sarah","")
df = data.frame(name,manager)
```

(Sarah is the top of the ladder) I'm just trying to do a simple lookup to pull in John's manager's manager (David). Ideally I would like a recursive loop in R that will run through my dataset and create an output that lists all the managers above each person such as this:

| name | manager | output |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John | Bill | Bill_David_Sarah |
| Bill | David | David_Sarah |
| David | Sarah | Sarah |
| Sarah |  |  |

Also please note, my data is not ordered in such a manner, and a manager can manage multiple people, its not one to one. Any help would be appreciated thanks!

Comment: Why not use `igraph`? this is hierarchical

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution with `igraph`. Create a directed graph from the data.frame, then a sequence of `lapply` loops extracts the information needed.

```r
name = c("John","Bill","David","Sarah")
manager = c("Bill","David","Sarah","")
df = data.frame(name,manager)

suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(igraph))

g <- graph_from_data_frame(df)
plot(g)
```

[image]

```r
ll <- lapply(V(g), \(v) all_simple_paths(g, from = v, to = V(g)[V(g) != v]))
ll <- lapply(ll, \(l) l[length(l)])
df$output <- sapply(ll[-length(ll)], \(l) {
  if(length(l) > 0) {
    inx <- eval(parse(text = l))[-1]
    nms <- names(ll)[ V(g)[inx] ]
    paste(nms[nms != ""], collapse = "_")
  } else ""
})

df
#>    name manager           output
#> 1  John    Bill Bill_David_Sarah
#> 2  Bill   David      David_Sarah
#> 3 David   Sarah            Sarah
#> 4 Sarah
```

<sup>Created on 2022-05-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Hey thanks so much for your response. This does work for the small example data set, but for some reason when I use my larger data set with the same structure this doesnt work.

Not sure how your code segment works:

`ll <- lapply(V(g), \(v) all_simple_paths(g, from = v, to = V(g)[V(g) != v]))
ll <- lapply(ll, \(l) l[length(l)])
df$output <- sapply(ll[-length(ll)], \(l) {
  if(length(l) > 0) {
    inx <- eval(parse(text = l))[-1]
    nms <- names(ll)[ V(g)[inx] ]
    paste(nms[nms != ""], collapse = "_")
  } else ""
})`

Comment: @GilBismut Can you post a larger data set? For instance, `dput(head(df, 20))`.